# How to Separate Disjoint Regions?

Tags: regions

For an examplary stl-file, which consists of two objects

```
spik=Import["...*.stl"]
```

[image]

I would like to separate the two single regions within `spik`.

```
RegionDisjoint[spik] (* True*)
```

gives True.

My question:

How to separate the single regions inside spik?
Thanks !

Comment: [`ConnectedMeshComponents`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConnectedMeshComponents.html)?

Comment: @LukasLang Thanks, that seems to solve my question!

Comment: I would like to know the reason why this question was closed ( and couldn'd find the " simple mistake". ) @LucasLang gave a helpful answer in his comment, which isn't obvious.  And certainly of great interest to all who deal with Mathematicas Regionfunctionality!

Comment: I think it's more the "can easily be found in the documentation" part of the closing-reason. I tend to view that reason for closing questions as a "this question is answered directly by a given documentation page, so a separate answer would be mostly pointless". (Note that this doesn't necessarily mean that it's always easy to find said page if you don't know what to look for)